# Safari possible floating issue

Tags: jquery, css, safari, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm using Masonry to create a tiled portfolio grid. I'm using a 12 column grid and several different widths for my tiled items. Here is what it looks like on Chrome and Firefox:

[image: chrome screenshot]

And Safari:

[image: safari screenshot]

I have tried playing with the calc, float, box-sizing, and every other CSS declaration I can get my hands on. Oddly enough, if you size the window on Safari it will fix itself at certain widths, which was what made me believe it was the CSS calc (and sub pixel rounding).

Because Safari rounds down for sub pixel rendering, the items are always smaller than the container.

See the code here: http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/pen/FijEh

```
.item {
width: 33.33%
width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3)
width: -moz-calc(100% / 3)
width: calc(100% / 3)
display: inline-block
height: 0
float: left
padding-bottom: 25%
border: 1px solid #333
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect cannot be entirely replicated in Safari, but can be mimicked by removing the calc() functions and using slightly smaller percentages.

http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/pen/GsEpy

```
.item
    width: 33%
```